# Project Laravel 404 Not Found in nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5

When installing nginx to use it with my laravel project, I believe that the routes do not work, it indicates the following error: 404 Not Found when trying to enter: http://127.0.0.1/project/public/login.

[nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv6eM.png)

Comment: The following is my nginx file .conf.

Comment: please attach your nginx config file(s) to your question

Comment: Please attach the configuration to the question - there is no need to use an image for a raw text file

Comment: edit the publication and attach the image of the nginx.conf file